# Does unitary transformation preserves the max of norm-2 of lower dimensional vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\{\mathbf{e}_i\in\mathbb{R}^n, i=1,...,N\}$. Apply a unitary transformation of the form $\mathbf{U}_N\otimes\mathbf{I}_n$ to this vector set and reach to vector set $\{\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^n, i=1,...,N\}$. If  $\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{e}_i=\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{1}^T_N/\sqrt{N}$ is a row of unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}_N$. is the following true:

$\max_i\|\mathbf{e}_i\|_2=\max_i\|\mathbf{x}_i\|_2$?

$\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes norm-2 and superscript $T$ denotes transpose.

In other words, if $\mathbf{x}=(\mathbf{U}_N\otimes\mathbf{I}_n)\mathbf{e}$ where $\mathbf{e}=[\mathbf{e}_1^T\cdots \mathbf{e}_N^T]^T$ and $\mathbf{x}=[\mathbf{x}_1^T\cdots \mathbf{x}_N^T]^T$. Do we have the following equality ?

$\max_i\|\mathbf{e}_i\|_2=\max_i\|\mathbf{x}_i\|_2$

I know that $\|\mathbf{e}\|=\|\mathbf{x}\|$, but I was wondering if the it is true for the $\max_i\|\cdot\|_2$?

Thank you in advance for any proof/disproof and/or suggestions.